# HTML and PHP webdesign and formating

Tags: php, html, formatting, web-deployment

I nedd some help formating HTML for my website. I have created a html page for my contact form. Then a php page that corrects errors in my page. then I also created another php page that thanks the person for submitting a contact form. After they submit the contact form I want them php to do the following:

On the form processing page:

- say thank you
- Echo back the users first and last name.
- Show today's date
- Echo back the visitor's age in years
- If the visitor    is older than    55 indicate that they are entitled
  to a senior citizen    discount
- If    the visitor is 30-54 years old indicate that they are
  entitled to    a middle aged citizen discount
- If the visitor is younger than 17 indicate that they are entitle to a
  youth discount

  ```
  <?php echo "thanks for contacting us";?>
  ```

Comment: Use simple `if-else` in `php` and echo out HTML tags with corresponding data...

Comment: how can that be done?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do..? A bit of more code would help...

Comment: <?php 
echo "thanks for contacting us";

?>

Comment: I am trying to post the whole thing, I am new to this website and I am unsure how

Answer (score 1):

See..for you above provided code you can do this in `PHP` and `HTML` by..

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
//assuming you used this for age and have the rest form
      <input type="number" min="0" max="100" name="age">
</form>

<?php
$age = $_POST['age'];
echo date("m.d.y");
echo "Your age is :".$age. ", you are entitled to";
if($age > 55){
     echo 'Discount';
}
else if($age > 30 && $age < 55){
     echo 'Discount';
}
else if($age < 17){
    echo 'discount';
}
?>
```

It is a simple if-else conditon.
`$_POST` gets you the value from the form using `name` tag..I fyou want to generate any `HTML` tag in `PHP` just put it inside `echo`.Like this

`echo "<p class="text" id="new1">Sample para tag<p>";`

In the similar way you can generate nay html tag in php by just enclosing in `echo ' ';`

Comment: is there anyway i can email you my work so far and you can help me correct it ? I am going to try and edit this question to show you what i have. i posted a new question with more details. youre very smart please take a look
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894886/html-and-php-contact-form?noredirect=1#comment46049845_28894886

Comment: I have got some work...I will post your answer in the latest question page asap... :)

Comment: thank you so much! just add it to whatever i have so far and ill test it